# Parsing out css rule blocks

Tags: css, regex

Guys have such snippet of css

```
/**
    Correct default cursor behaviour across the site
    relies on body having cursor: default below.
*/
* { font-size: 12em; }
div {
  cursor: inherit;
}
html,
body,
#main-view-target {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: default;
  background: url("{ROOT}../img/bg.png")no-repeat;
}
```

Need to parse out all property blocks with regexp, but {ROOT|VERSION} meta instruction don't let me to do that. 
How to omit that instruction?

Comment: What kind of tool are you using. That is the minimum information we need to help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: X/Y problem; you don't need to (Y) parse all property blocks with regexp; rather, you need to (X) find a solution to some problem (which is what?), the solution to which you **think** is parsing property blocks with regexp. In general, you shouldn't try to parse CSS with regexp any more than you would parse HTML. The browser and its APIs know how to parse things much more efficiently and robustly than you. In this case, the browser has parsed the rules into its style sheet object, which you can examine and modify the value of with eg `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.backgroundImage`.

Comment: I'm using native C# Regex. Did you mean that? For testing regex I'm using regex101.com or Regex Coach

Comment: to torazaburo: I'm stick to that solution because of implementation of a programm which I can't rewrite. Otherwise I would choose diferrent way.

Answer (score 0):

```
({(?>[^}]+|(?:(?<={ROOT)|(?<={VERSION))})*})
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/W5g0v8qqev)

Comment: I've edited out your complaint about downvotes. __Do not add noise into your posts__, use comments for discussions related to the post. Read more: [Should SO have a prequalification process for membership to weed out the 'noise'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254448/3622940)

Comment: Could it be more general because I added one more placeholder {SETTING:[anyName]} and this pattern not working any more. Tried to play with it but without success.